# Cannot convert '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, hibernate, date, hql

the field definition

```
 /** Date. */
  @Column(columnDefinition = "datetime")
  private Date date;
```

setter

```
public void setDate(final Date date) {
    DateFormat dfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
      this.date = dfmt.parse(dfmt.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Does anyone have idea how to convert "zero date" into proper value ?
Because i have error:

```
Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 13 to TIMESTAMP
```

And even if i set "default" field and setter like this:

```
/** Date. */
      @Column
      private Date date;


public void setDate(final Date date) {
      this.date = date;   
  }
```

I'll still have the same problem....

Comment: It seems to me that 0000-00-00 00:00:00 does not correspond to any actual moment in time, and therefore it fundamentally cannot be converted to a timestamp value. What is the behavior you wanted? Do you want it to convert the invalid ISO date to a default value?

Comment: the next move after i get data(there are more than just one column in table) from table is to write this into XML but(!) i will not write Date value in to XML so i just want to get data from table and after then i will never call getDate() method.

Comment: "Do you want it to convert the invalid ISO date to a default value?" - yes, if it possible...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess here that you're using MySQL :-) It uses "zero dates" as [special placeholder](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/date-and-time-types.html) - unfortunatelly, JDBC can not handle them by default.

The solution is to specify "zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" as parameter to your MySQL connection (either in datasource URL or as an additional property), e.g.:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

This will cause all such values to be retrieved as NULLs.

Comment: Just a side note - this will convert zero dates to nulls during read but it won't convert nulls to zeros during save. I haven't find a way to save "0000-00-00" into a database through hibernate.

Comment: @serg555 - you're right. I've got to ask, though - why would you ever want to save "0000-00-00" into a database? NULLs exist for precisely this reason, this whole "0000-00-00" abomination is nothing but pain.

Comment: For the same reason why I would ever want to read zero dates - system  was designed that way and I have no control over it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the point in your code, where you format then parse again a date. This seems like an identical operation. Maybe you could elaborate?

---

If you want to give a default value to a date, you could do :

```
/** Jan 1, 1970 ; first moment in time in Java */
private static final Date NO_DATE = new Date(0L);

private Date date;

public void setDate(final Date date) {
     if (date == null) {
         this.date = NO_DATE;
     } else {
         this.date = date;
     }
}
```

Note : the annotation are optionnal, here I didn't add them.

In this code, you could substitute what you want to the condition, and to the default value.

You could also add a similar setter, that would take a String argument, and check for your special "00000..." value. This would allow for setting the field either with a Date, or with a String.