# How do i map a sql Time type to a java type using hibernate?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I've got a sql data type of TIME.  Now, the data for 12:00 AM is stored as 00:00:00.

In the POJO that is mapped to the table, I have given the datatype as java.util.Date as per the hibernate specification. However, on loading a row that has the data type 00:00:00 i get this exception.

```
Cannot convert value '00:00:00' from column 18 to TIMESTAMP
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: [Cannot convert '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to TIMESTAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363527/cannot-convert-0000-00-00-000000-to-timestamp)

Comment: @Jarandinor - i'm not storing the data as a date in the database. I'm storing it as a TIME datatype.

Answer (score 1):

For SQLServer you can use something like this. It should also work for time types I guess.(I don't know if it changes for other DB types)

```
private Date lockedUntil;
@Column(name="DATE", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Comment: I'm storing only a time and not a date in the database. Hence i would want to use a TIME type only.

Comment: See the following statement above: "It should also work for time types I guess." So just play around with changing the columnDefinition to "TIME". Just use this as a starting point and play around a bit until it clicks.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in xml? Not able to do this.

Comment: Sry, didn't need to get into XML mapping so far. You will have to wait for someone more capable to come around.

Comment: I am facing pretty much exactly the same problem. How do you set a time given in the form 'hh:mm:ss' using hibernate annotated pojo? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to just set a TIME column instead of a DATETIME?

Comment: Hey Carsten, yes I have but made no difference. In the end I was able to solve it using `java.sql.Time` instead of `java.util.Date` (When using `java.sql.Time`, you need to remove the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)` annotation as it is no longer needed). I don't think this solution is neat though as it means having to work with java.sql objects in business logic code that may not have any direct association with database work of any kind.