# how to insert Timestamp in database?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd 
>   hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Here is my java code:

```
<%  int reg;

        String sdate = request.getParameter("sdate");
        //Timestamp ts=request.get
      //out.println(sdate);
         String text = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
       Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(text);
       // Timestamp ts1=Timestamp.valueOf(sdate);
       //  Timestamp ts2=Timestamp.valueOf(edate);
    try{
          String s;
      Format formatter;
     Date date = new Date(sdate);
     //out.println(date);
      formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
     s = formatter.format(date);
     out.println(s);
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("insert into c1 values(?)");
                           // ps.setString(1,ts);
         ps.setTimestamp(1,ts);



                            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
                            if(i==1)
                        {
                       pw.println("record inserted");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        pw.println("not iNSERTED");
                        }
                        //cn.close();

                       }
                 catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            out.println(e.toString());
                        }

    %>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Welcom to SO. Unfortunately, that's not the way it works here.  Although you may get an answer, we prefer that you do your own research, tell us what you've done and explain what you don't understand.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for details.  Questions of the form "here's my code, please fix it" tend to get downvoted and/or put on hold.

Comment: @Shakti, please read jim garrison's comment. I agree. Try to change your question so that you can show to use that you have attempted to figure out a solution yourself. For now though just to welcome you to SO, you can have a look at my answer below. It involves you using the hyphen character instead of the colon character when you write the date format

Comment: You don't show the exception traceback or identify the line that got the error.  You're holding back on us.  But observe that a date of 0000-00-00 is invalid, while with your SimpleDateFormatter you're using `:` where you should use `-`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the user has withheld critical information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shakti, you need to address the error. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`

and then have a look at the way you've formatted your date.
You'll need to change your line below

```
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
```

to:

```
 formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Notice the difference and use of the hyphen character in the date instead of the colon character which you're using.

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, so after @sotirios' comment, I decided to do some extra research and I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363750/445312) and learned something. You can't give a 0000-00... date configuration because MySQL [uses "zero dates" as special placeholder

The solution plain and simple is to change the date string from

```
String text = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
```

to at least

```
String text = "0001-01-01 00:00:00";
```

*And if you really want to send 0000-00-... date strings I believe the solution is to specify "zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" as a parameter to your MySQL connection (either in datasource URL or as an additional property), e.g.:*

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

*This will cause all such values to be sent as NULLs.*

Comment: I don't believe the error is here. The error is thrown from the `Timestamp.valueOf`.

Comment: @HotLicks ahahaha hotlicks, chill bro, Sotirios is another fellow member trying to help the OP. he IS NOT the OP :P hehe, Sotirios is just communicating with another poster - me - to try and tell me that the solution may not be what I posted.

Comment: OK, apologies to all (except the OP).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I dont think Hotlicks is being sarcastic unless im missing the joke here, I believe he confused you for being the OP :O

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Aha I liked your positivity though that his comment might have been a sarcastic joke lol ;)

Answer (score 4):

This

```
String text = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
```

is not a valid date. There is no month or day with a value of `0`.

The `Timestamp.valueOf(text)` will not be able to parse it.

At least use

```
String text = "0000-01-01 00:00:00";
```

Answer (score 0):

i use the jdbc's native timestamp type:

```
Date date = myobject.getDate();

cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.myproc(?)}");
cstmt.setTimestamp("date", new Timestamp(date.getTime())
cstmt.execute();
```