# Grails 2.5.6 Date type error when upgrading from Grals 2.1.1

Tags: grails

I've upgraded my grails app from 2.1.1 to 2.5.6 and I'm now getting a problem with dates.

I have an MS-SQL database with a list of dates stored as `date` types. So they appear as 'yyyy-mm-dd' in the database.

My domain class is:

```
class Bank_holidays {

    Date date

    static constraints = {
        date format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'        
    }
    static mapping = {
        version false        
    }
}
```

And in my controller I am simply doing:

```
List bankHolidays = Bank_holidays.list()
```

But since upgrading to Grails 2.5.6 (from Grails 2.1.1) I am now hitting the following error:

Timestamp format must be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`

How do I resolve this error now in the later version of Grails?

Comment: "So they appear as 'yyyy-dd-mm' in the database." and "date format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'" contradict to each other. As well as `class Bank_holidays` and `Bank_Holidays.list()`

Comment: Sorry - my typo it should have been Bank_holidays.list()

Comment: Regarding the date format, perhaps I should set out the requirements.  The date is stored as a 'Date' type in the database, so when I view the date using the SQL Management Studio it displays as yyyy-mm-dd. However in my Grails view I want to display the date as dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: @Simon refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119096/how-to-insert-timestamp-in-database